# Please help me with instalation of 64bit version

Tags: installation, 12.10

Hi, I have Intel(R) Core(TM) Quad CPU q8200 @ 2.33Ghz but I wasn't able to install the 64bit version, **Ubuntu 12.10 desktop-amd64**. Can you help find the right ( x64 ? ) distribution that would work on my PC?

Comment: You use the "amd64" version to install 6 4bit Ubuntu on intel processors. (see the link I gave you for more information. If you are having a problem, check the md5sum and update your question to describe the problem. Could be almost anything.

Comment: The question named as duplicate does not seem to give an answer to this question. So if the question needs to be closed it should be closed with a different reason, but not with a duplicate to a question not answering this.

Comment: @txwikinger Assuming you think this should be closed *temporarily* until the OP provides enough information, why should we spend the time reopening it so we can close it so we can reopen it again?

Comment: @Vronline Please edit your question to explain exactly how you tried to install and exactly what happened. Please provide as many details as possible, including the full and exact text of any error messages. Depending on what happened you may have to try installing again to record the details. Please also [MD5SUM your ISO image](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) and [check your installation media for defects](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck#Verifying_the_CD.2BAC8-DVD_Integrity) (this applies for both CD/DVD media and USB media).

Comment: @EliahKagan What I am saying is that the link to the duplicate question on top is false and hence it is not helpful. It should be reopened and  either get a proper duplicate link, or closed without one. Why is there a concept of temporarily closed questions?

Comment: @txwikinger Most closures are considered at least potentially temporary, as a question may be improved and reopened. This is less often so when a question is closed as a duplicate. I recommend asking on meta about this if you're unfamiliar with that--it is a core concept for closing and reopening. You haven't suggested a new duplicate. If you have one in mind, please tell us. Otherwise, we don't know this is a duplicate at all, and considering that so few details have been given in the question, I doubt we could know. I've requested info in my previous comment to make the question answerable.

Comment: @EliahKagan Well.. I am concerned about the fact that false information is created. I just suggested possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

**amd64** is used for both AMD and Intel processors, as they have (more or less) the same architecture. Your Core Quad already supports the installer that you downloaded, so you just need to continue!

Anyway, if it's not compatible with your computer, the installer won't be able to start and will show an alert message, so don't worry!

Answer (score 0):

Further information you find here:
http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/64-Bit-Architektur?redirect=no

Do you install by USB-stick or CD/DVD? Actually I cannot recommend the first.

Good luck
Wim